# Apply Style From Resource to ListView.ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm working with XAML/WPF in VS 2012. I'll admit I don't really understand templating and styling very well yet.

I've defined a style in my application.xaml file like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ContactGroups" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <!-- Styling omitted here -->
</Style>
```

Now I want to apply this style to my list view but I cannot figure out where to apply this styling, i.e., where to put the code to set the style. I've omitted lots of attributes here to keep things shorter:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedGroup, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="140" Height="25">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [StaticResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) markup extension to set Style on `ItemContainerStyle` of ListBox:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedGroup, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContactGroups}" >
```

Comment: Runs and compiles without errors but my styling isn't getting applied. I'm really confused as to how that could be. When get the hex for the colors being used and search for them in my XAML (or entire application) the colors don't come up anywhere. I suspect your answer is correct and I have some other problem.

Comment: Yeah for the question you posted. This is the way you achieve it. Not sure about your other problem.

Comment: Consider opening another question with details in there for your style so that it can be looked on by more people.

Comment: I think it might be a Win 8.x bug. See my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686509/wpf-ff-color-bug-on-windows-8-1-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you only want this style to be applied to this list, but if not you could simply remove the `x:Key="ContactGroups"` from the style and it should be applied to all list items.

If you are looking to only target this listview an option would be to add the style to the resources of the list view:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedGroup, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <!-- Styling omitted here -->
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="140" Height="25">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Edit: Based on your comment below this may be the approach you want to take:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ContactGroups}" />
</ListView.Resources>
```

This way your style stays defined in the App.xaml.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might actually point me in the right direction. I wonder if I have another "global" style somewhere that is being applied to my list causing the problem I mentioned in the comments above. Thanks for the suggestion on using the local resources. I'm actually trying to move my styling out of the xaml window right now because the Window has gotten too complex and difficult to read.

Comment: Oic.  In that case I have one more option that you might prefer.  I'll add it above.