# WPF #FF Color Bug on Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I've ran across what appears to be some kind of color related but in WPF/XAML on Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2012. Using Snoop, I can see that every color assigned as hexadecimal is showing FF appended to the beginning of the hex. So, for example, #DDDDDD becomes #FFDDDDDD.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1 (don't ask)... Latest updates installed as far as I know.

I made a really simple WPF test application. I'm assigning colors in the application like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Label1" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#18537E" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#DDDDDD" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>        
</Application.Resources>
```

My Window (not complete xaml):

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource GridBorder}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=DisplayText}" Style="{StaticResource Label1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: WPF FF Color Bug]

Can anyone else verify that this is a problem or tell me what I might be doing wrong that's causing this?

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything wrong.  Snoop shows the full hex codes, *including the alpha channel*, for colors.  `#FFDDDDDD` is exactly the same as `#DDDDDD`, since the alpha is 100% by default.

Comment: OK, I guess what threw me is that we are having an issue where the colors in one application do appear wrong. Will have to gather more info on that one and post if necessary.